# How to resize a picturebox according with an image (.jpg or .png)?

Tags: vb.net, resize, picturebox

I have a picturebox with `SizeMode = Zoom` and with an image (1200x600) in it.

I set `form size = screen size` and after I set and `picturebox height size = screen height size`.

How to set `width` of picturebox, using code, so as so the image (from picturebox) fits perfectly in picturebox even if it exceeds the `screen size`?

I work with `Visual Basic` code.

Comment: Anchor the picturebox on all four sides? No code needed

Comment: Yes, in this case picturebox size = screen size, but I need picture height size = screen size (it is simple), but I don't know how to resize width of picturebox so as so the image fits perfectly in picturebox.

Comment: `PictureBox1.ClientSize = New Size(PictureBox1.Image.Width, PictureBox1.ClientSize.Height)`?

Comment: Well that depends on what picture you have. By using `SizeMode = Zoom` it will keep the height:width of your picture, so if you have a landscape image the height will be limited by the width, and a portrait image will have the width limited by the height... Is there a property to check the actual image size vs what it should be?

Comment: @ProGrammer : The actual image size is `PictureBox1.Image.Size`, the other I don't know (and don't think so).